# Adding a total of items swiped with Arduino Uno and RFID tags

Tags: sum, arduino, microcontroller, rfid

I am developing an RFID based handheld device that enables a user to swipe a product and total their purchase on the device. What would the code be to setting the RFID tags to display the price as well as adding the tags together once swiped?

Is this possible with the Arduino Uno? Here's what I have so far as it's just displaying the RFID tag once swiped.

```cpp
int RFIDResetPin = 13;

char tag1[13] = "5000B9A7155B"
char tag2[13] = "5000B9A7155B"
char tag3[13] = "5000B9A7155B"
char tag4[13] = "5000B9A7155B"
char tag5[13] = "5000B9A7155B"

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);  // Connect to the serial port.
}

void loop () {
    byte i = 0;
    byte val = 0;
    byte code[6];
    byte checksum = 0;
    byte bytesread = 0;
    byte tempbyte = 0;

    if(Serial.available() > 0) {
        if((val = Serial.read()) == 2) {  // Check for header
            bytesread = 0;
            while (bytesread < 12) {  // Read 10 digit code + 2 digit checksum
                if( Serial.available() > 0) {
                    val = Serial.read();
                    if((val == 0x0D)||
                       (val == 0x0A)||
                       (val == 0x03)||
                       (val == 0x02)) { // If header or stop bytes before the 10 digit reading.

                        break;  // Stop reading
                    }

                    // Do ASCII/hexadecimal conversion:
                    if ((val >= '0') && (val <= '9')) {
                        val = val - '0';
                    }
                    else
                        if ((val >= 'A') && (val <= 'F')) {
                            val = 10 + val - 'A';
                        }

                    // Every two hex-digits, add byte to code:
                    if (bytesread & 1 == 1) {
                        // Make some space for this hex-digit by
                        // shifting the previous hex-digit with 4 bits to the left:
                        code[bytesread >> 1] = (val | (tempbyte << 4));

                        if (bytesread >> 1 != 5) {             // If we're at the checksum byte,
                            checksum ^= code[bytesread >> 1];  // Calculate the checksum... (XOR)
                        };
                    }
                    else {
                        tempbyte = val;                        // Store the first hex digit first...
                    };

                    bytesread++;                               // Ready to read next digit
                }
            }

            // Output to Serial:

            if (bytesread == 12) {                             // If 12 digit read is complete
                Serial.print("5-byte code: ");
                for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    if (code[i] < 16)
                        Serial.print("0");
                    Serial.print(code[i], HEX);
                    Serial.print(" ");
                }
                Serial.println();

                Serial.print("Checksum: ");
                Serial.print(code[5], HEX);
                Serial.println(code[5] == checksum ? " -- passed." : " -- error.");
                Serial.println();
            }
            bytesread = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the prices from? Do you plan to have something like a database of prices on your device? Or do you want to query an external DB over the air?